# What is the name of the header file that contains the declaration of malloc?

Tags: c++, c, malloc

What is the name of the header file that contains the declaration of the `malloc()` function in C and C++?

Answer (score 56):

It's in `stdlib.h` (C) and `cstdlib` (C++).

In general, for such questions, just try to look on google: "c++ function". Most often the first hit will point to cplusplus.com for me containing a complete reference to the standard stuff.

Comment: cplusplus.com is not a very good reference. It contains subtle but important errors in descriptions of many functions in the C standard. No idea how accurate it is for C++ stuff.

Comment: Haven't had any real issues yet (ignoring cross platform differences).

Comment: One example that comes to mind is its documentation of what `scanf` returns.

Comment: This has now, ironically, become one of the top google results for this search.

Comment: @ZimriLeisher Psst! Recursion at work!